# socket.io disconnects when using breakpoints in client code

Tags: socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

What is the best way to debug my app that uses socket.io ?

The app is working fine but when I set breakpoints in the app using the chrome dev tools, after a few seconds, the socket.io client disconnects from the server ( or the server closes the connection), probably because of the client being idle while I inspect my breakpoints ..

What am I missing here ? How do you all use the chrome dev tools your apps that use socket.io ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled polling in transports and that seems to have done the trick. This is what my transports look like now.

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using socket.io version 2.20 (the latest version as of Jan 2020), and stepping through breakpoints using Chrome on the client side. The solution was to (temporarily) augment the Engine.IO timeout settings like this:

```
const io = ...; // initialize socket.io how you wish
io.eio.pingTimeout = 1200000; // 20 minutes, plenty of time to debug!
io.eio.pingInterval = 5000;  // can change this if you like
```

Note that older versions of socket.io supported this approach to assigning these settings:

```
const io = ... initialize socket.io how you wish;
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 1200000);
io.set('heartbeat interval', 5000);
```

When you are done debugging, don't forget to put these back to reasonable values (or rely on the default values).